# How to add class to list item and remove it from previous item

Tags: jquery, html

I need add class `orange` to item list on click and remove it when I click on the next item.

**Markup:**

```
  <ul class="navbar-custom clearfix">
       <li><a href="#start"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#description"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#syntax"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#scrollbar"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#rotations"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#rotations-rotated"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#source"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#follow"></a></li>
   </ul>
```

**Script:**

```
$("nav").find("li").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("orange");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing that, `toggleClass` is not enough,

```
$("nav").find("li").click(function () {
    //remove all the orange class set with the li elements except the current element
    $("li.orange").not($(this).addClass("orange")).removeClass("orange");
    // add class orange to the current element.
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ee1onzsh/)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
var navlis = $("nav").find("li");
navlis.click(function () {
    navlis.not(this).removeClass("orange");
    $(this).toggleClass("orange");
});
```

Comment: If you click an `li` twice, then nothing would have the `orange` class. Is that intended?

Comment: @SpoonMeiser: yes. as OP want visibility to toggle.